# How to use hibernate with Spring MVC properly?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working on a small Spring MVC/ Hibernate project which I keep in the following link, `https://github.com/Chaklader/backend` I'm getting this error message after including hibernate,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.backend.dao.CustomerDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/backend/config/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [hibernate_sequence]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
```

The `web.xml` file is as following,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>backend</display-name>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>backend</display-name>
        <servlet-name>backend</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>backend</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>Backend WS</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:com/backend/config/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

the `applicationContext.xml` file is as following,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.backend.dao"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.backend.model"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/backend/config/backenddb.properties" />

    <bean id="mysqlDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://${mysql.jdbc.host}:${mysql.jdbc.port}/${mysql.jdbc.databaseName}?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>


    <!--********** SessionFactory **********-->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.backend.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--********** TransactionManager **********-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

The controller source file is namely `HomeController.java` provided below,

```
 package com.backend.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeControllers {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(){

        return "home";
    }
}
```

My project structure can be seen here ( or, in github),

[image]

I think the main error message is `Error creating bean with name 'customerDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;`. How to solve this issue ?

EDIT:

When I add the following portion of the code inside the `applicationContext.xml` file, the program breaks down. How can I add hibernate definition inside the a Spring bean configuration file properly ?

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.backend.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: post your controller

Comment: There is not much code there, however, I posted w/ the project structure. You can also have a look in the Github. Controller package is mentioned in the backend-servlet.xml file and that calls home.jsp from the JSP folder.

Comment: Where you use this customerDAO

Comment: I'm intended to write a web service and the classes form the dao package will be called inside the service package. I haven't write anything there. First I would like to resolve the error.

Comment: I can't see where you're using this customerDAO

Comment: I haven't write it yet, see the services package is empty and the classes there will be calling the source files of the dao package (say, CustomerService.java will call CustomerDAO.java). Now, I haven't write the CustomerService.java. See the project structure image.

Comment: Try changing your @GeneratedValue from strategy = GenerationType.AUTO to strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY. MySQL uses auto incrememeting, but the error message leads me to believe its looking for a sequence

Comment: I totally agree with @greyfox here since the bottom line of the exception is `Schema-validation: missing table [hibernate_sequence]`

Comment: I still get the same error message, perhaps I will just use SQL Strings w/ JDBC. However, I'm still open for answers.

Comment: did you change to GenerationType.IDENTITY on every one of the model classes?

Comment: Yes, I have 4 files in the model package, I changed in all of them. Now, started to using JDBC w/ SQL String

Comment: Just create the missing table (or set the schema to update instead of validate). Although I wouldn't recommend that setting for production.